# Gulp concat and minify with a watch task

Tags: javascript, gulp, minify, concatenation

I'm trying to setup a some Gulp tasks. I want to concatenate some JS files, minify them to create 1 JS file, but I want this done each time a change has been made in the original JS files but I can't seem to get the 'watch' task running properly

This is my Gulpfile.js

```
gulp.task('minify', ['watch', 'scripts'], function(){
  gulp.src('themes/corp-fluid/js/dist/**/*.js')
          .pipe(minify({
            ext:{
              src:'-debug.js',
              min:'.js'
            },
            ignoreFiles: ['-min.js']
          }))
          .pipe(gulp.dest('themes/corp-fluid/js/dist'));
});

gulp.task('scripts', function(){
  return gulp.src(['themes/corp-fluid/js/slick.js', 'themes/corp-fluid/js/functions.js'])
          .pipe(concat('main.js'))
          .pipe(gulp.dest('themes/corp-fluid/js/dist'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function(){
  gulp.watch('themes/corp-fluid/js/**/*.js');
});
```

Comment: here i have documented a small gulp starter app check out https://github.com/wavemeetu/gulp-seed-app
with minifying and merge into a single file

Comment: Thanx, I used your method and it works :)

Comment: Dude the link's broken.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things.  You need to call something in your 
'watch' task, so

```
gulp.task('watch', function(){
  gulp.watch('themes/corp-fluid/js/**/*.js', ['minify']);
});
```

and simplify the first line of your 'minify' task to

```
gulp.task('minify', ['scripts'], function(){
```

you don't need to call the 'watch' task again there.  And finally you would be running the whole thing with

```
gulp watch
```

Answer (score 1):

Gulpfile with  sass, js concat, minify, and watch task.
You need change proxy domain name to yor domain name in browser-sync task, and change array of files in concat_js task.

```js
var gulp = require('gulp')
var browserSync = require('browser-sync')
var sass = require('gulp-sass')
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var minify = require('gulp-minify');

//Sass
gulp.task('sass', function () {   
    return gulp.src('app/sass/**/*.scss')     
            .pipe(sass()) 
            // pipe(gulp.dest('app/css')) 
            .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css/'))
});

//browser reload
gulp.task('browser-sync', function () {
    browserSync({ 
        notify: false, 
        proxy: "http://front-end" //Your domain name
    });
});

//concat
gulp.task('concat_js', function() {
  //An array of files is required for the correct order of contact
  return gulp.src(['app/js/_helpers.js',
                   'app/js/_cookie_notice.js']) //file array need for 
    .pipe(concat('all.js'))
    .pipe(minify({
        ext:{
            src:'',
            min:'.min.js'
        },
        noSource: true}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/js/'));
});

//watch
gulp.task('watch', ['browser-sync', 'sass'], function () {
    gulp.watch('app/sass/**/*.scss', ['sass']);    
    gulp.watch('app/js/*.js', ['concat_js']);  
    gulp.watch('app/**/*.*', browserSync.reload);    
});



gulp.task('default', ['watch', 'sass', 'concat_js']);
```

*Note: An array of files in task concat_js is required for the correct order of file contact.*

Comment: An array of files in task concat_js is required for the correct order of file contact.

Comment: See https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/1737 I am not sure the src array ensures any particular order - the files are retrieved asynchronously.